# Why is close() method of the resource called before catch in a try-with-resources construct in Java?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I happened to realize, that this is the case. See this example below:

```
public class AutoClosableTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (MyClosable instance = new MyClosable()) {
            if (true) {
                System.out.println( "try" );
                throw new Exception("Foo");
            }
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( "Catched" );
        } finally {
            System.out.println( "Finally" );
        }
    }

    public static class MyClosable implements AutoCloseable {
        @Override
        public void close() throws Exception {
            System.out.println( "Closed." );
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

> try 
>   Closed. 
>   Catched 
>   Finally

### Question

The try-with-resources is designed to avoid the messy finally sections with null checks and to avoid the leaked resources. Why are the resources closed BEFORE the catch section? What is the reason/idea/limitation behind it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer can be found in [JLS §14.20.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2); the key parts are the last two paragraphs, particularly the last sentence of the penultimate paragraph (I've emphasized it):

> A `try-with-resources` statement with at least one `catch` clause and/or a `finally` clause is called an *extended* `try-with-resources` statement.
>
> The meaning of an extended `try-with-resources` statement:
>
> ```
> try ResourceSpecification
>     Block
> [Catches]
> [Finally]
> ```
>
> is given by the following translation to a basic `try-with-resources` statement nested inside a `try-catch` or `try-finally` or `try-catch-finally` statement:
>
> ```
> try {
>     try ResourceSpecification
>         Block
> }
> [Catches]
> [Finally]
> ```
>
> The effect of the translation is to put the resource specification "inside" the `try` statement. **This allows a `catch` clause of an extended `try-with-resources` statement to catch an exception due to the automatic initialization or closing of any resource.**
>
> Furthermore, all resources will have been closed (or attempted to be closed) by the time the `finally` block is executed, in keeping with the intent of the `finally` keyword.